# interior and closure strictly from definitions.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $A \subset X$.

Let int$A$ (interior of $A$ in $X$) be the union of all open sets contained in $A$. That is,

int$A= \bigcup_{B \in \tau_A} B$.

Let cl$A$ (closure of $A$ in $X$) be the intersection of every closed set containing $A$.

I need to show that the boundary of $A$, which is the set difference of the two defined above, contains every limit point of $A$.

Attempt:

Let $x$ be a limit point of $A$, then every neighborhood of $x$, say $U$ intersects $A$ nontrivially, that is, there exists a $y \neq x$ such that $y \in U \cap A$.

I need to show $x \in$ every closed set containing $A$ and that it is not in any open set contained in $A$. really stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot prove it, since it is false. If, say, $X=\Bbb R$, endowed with its usual topology, and if $A=(-1,1)$, then the boundary of $A$ is $\{1,-1\}$.  But the set of limit points of $A$ is $[-1,1]$, and $[-1,1]\not\subset\{1,-1\}$.

Comment: oh wow thanks! so are all limit points contained in the closure OF the interior or is that false too?

Comment: Just to be sure: did you mean to write “closure of the interior”? I ask this because you capitalized the word “OF” and I don't know whether or not that has some meaning.

Comment: yes no meaning I mean cl(int($A$))

Comment: No, it is not true. Take $A=\left\{\frac1n\,\middle|\,n\in\Bbb N\right\}$. The $0$ is a limit point of $A$, but the interior of $A$ is empty, and then so is its closure.